# Why the expression in java not following BODMAS rule?

Tags: java

```
System.out.println(90 + 9 - 10);
```

This code is giving output as 89 by following BODMAS rule.

But when I am trying to compile and run code below

```
System.out.println(90 - 9 + 10);
```

it is showing 91 (not following BODMAS rule) instead of 71. Why?

Comment: What do you think it should print? 91 looks correct to me

Comment: @GrahamSavage I am expecting result as 71 not 91.

Comment: @ShashankAgarwal It'd only be 71 if + has higher precendence than -, and/or if + and - are right-associative. Neither of those conditions are true, so you wouldn't get 71.

Comment: Thanks. I thought '+' has higher precedence than '-'

Comment: @ShashankAgarwal * and / have higher precedence than + and -, but * and / are same, and + and - are same.

Comment: BODMAS is actually nonsense; division and multiplication have the same precedence, as do addition and subtraction.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations - particularly "These mnemonics may be misleading when written this way, especially if the user is not aware that multiplication and division are of equal precedence, as are addition and subtraction."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that + and - have the same precedence, so they are evaluated left-to-right (+ and - are both left-associative operators). So, 90 - 9 + 10 = 81 + 10 = 91.

Answer (score 1):

Per operator precedence `+` and `-` comes under same precedence priority and gets evaluated `left -> right` and so the expression `90 - 9 + 10` gets evaluated like `90 -9` first -> resulting in `81` and then `81+10 = 91` which is your result.

In case you want to alter this sequence then parenthesize them using `()` like

```
90 - (9 + 10)
```

Which will result in `71` cause in this case expression under `()` will be evaluated first resulting in `19` and then `90 - 19` which is what you are looking for.